# Send a UIImage through an email

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Given that I have a UIImage that is stored in a local variable:

```
UIImage *myImage = (Some image extracted somewhere)
```

How do I add this image as an attachment through MFMailComposeViewController ?

The image isn't stored on the users device and it's simply available at runtime.

So I can't access this image through a file name as other questions/examples have demonstrated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.9);
NSString *attachmentName = @"Any name.jpg"
[mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:attachmentName];
```

Comment: It's the desire name of the attachment, to be show in your email. I edit the answer to be more clear.

Comment: You may want to consider using `0.9` instead of `1.0` in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.  There is often a significant size decrease with almost no noticeable quality decrease, which could be helpful for e-mailed photos.